# Calculating $a^n\pmod m$ in the general case

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, tetration

It is well known, that

$$a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod m ,$$

if $\gcd(a,m)=1.$

So, $a^n\pmod m$ can be calculated by reducing n modulo $\phi(m)$.

But, for the tetration modulo $m$

$$a \uparrow \uparrow n\pmod{m},$$

I need the general case, where $a$ and $m$ need not to be coprime.

Which reduction can I use in this case ?

Is there an easier method to calculate the tetration modulo m without
using the reductions modulo $m , \phi(m) , \phi(\phi(m)) ...$ ?

I tried to write a program in PARI, but I failed because reducing modulo
$\phi(m)$ does not work, if a and m are not coprime.

Comment: How large are each of the numbers? (approximately)

Comment: If $gcd(a,m)>1$ then $a^n \pmod{n}$ will not be equal to 1 in general. The easiest method of computing exponentiation in that case is to use binary exponentiation (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

Comment: m is not large, but without reduction, $a \uparrow \uparrow n$ cannot be calculated, if n>=6 or so.

Comment: At some point, the exponent gets to big, so I must reduce it in a proper way.

Comment: An example problem would be $7 \uparrow \uparrow 6\ (mod\ 97)$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587652/doubts-about-a-nested-exponents-modulo-n-homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can say in general is 
$$a^k \equiv a^{k+\lambda(n)} \bmod n $$
for all $a$ (including those not co-prime to $n$) and all $k \geq \max v_p(n)$.

Here, $\lambda$ is [Carmichael’s function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and $v_p(n)$ is the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Bad news for my problem ...

Comment: @Peter Why is this bad news for your problem? Your "example" problem modulo 97 does not suggest that your $k$ would ever get crippling large. (And you can replace $\la$ by $\varphi$ if this is worrying you.)

Comment: Does this mean I can reduce modulo $n,\phi(n),\phi(\phi(n)),...$, unless the modulo becomes too small ? Must I check the factorization of n in any step, or successive of $n,\phi(n),\phi(\phi(n)),...$ ?

Answer (score 5):

> @sheldon I still do not have a proper algorithm to calculate tetrations modulo m, do you have one?

Peter,

This is the pari-gp code I have that I think works for all the cases I've tried.  Using this code, I verified that the solution m=34276387, posted in a comment earlier as the smallest prime factor of $(2\uparrow\uparrow5+3\uparrow\uparrow5)$ is also a prime factor of  $(2\uparrow\uparrow6+3\uparrow\uparrow6)$ and  $(2\uparrow\uparrow7+3\uparrow\uparrow7)$, and also for all n>7.  Powertower modular arithmetic seems to converge to a value independent of tetration height fairly quickly.  This pari-gp code implements the combination of the Euler phi reduction, and the power2n binary exponentiation function for $(b\uparrow\uparrow i) \bmod m$.  The key is the combination of the exit conditions, and the $\log_2(m)$ repeating pattern starting position, which I got from [the answer to your other recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631640/lower-and-upper-bounds-for-the-length-of-phi-chains-wanted).  Then we know, for some integer $k \lt \log_2(m)$,

$$b^{k} \equiv b^{ k+\phi(m)} \pmod m$$

This reduces the problem to $b^z \equiv (b\uparrow\uparrow i) \pmod m$ where $z=(b\uparrow\uparrow (i-1)) \bmod \phi(m)$, so long as $\log_2(m)<z<b\uparrow\uparrow i$.    This requires more work; it would be nice to prove that the exit conditions identified in the pari-gp code are sufficient but for now, working pari-gp code will have to do.  **Code update**, I generalized the boundary condition for $((b\uparrow\uparrow i) \bmod m)$ where m is a multiple with n>=2, $n(b\uparrow\uparrow i)$, which is a boundary condition for the math equations.  This is fixed in the pari-gp code.

The repeating patterns can be shorter then $\phi(m)$, but that isn't required.  I have another much slower pari-gp program that brute force finds the shortest chains, and the final results match with this version.  Let me know if you find any bugs or missing boundary conditions.  I have tested it fairly exhaustively against the power2n code for prime values of p, with the power tower height=4, and against the slower version for other heights, and for non-prime values of p.

The code can do other interesting stuff, like calculate an arbitrary number of right hand digits of Graham's number, $(3\uparrow\uparrow 13) \bmod 10^{12}=262464195387$, which is stable for i>13.

```
/* calculates (b^^i) mod m */
reducetower(b,m,i) = {
  local(n,rz,log2p);
  /* these are the recursion exit conditions */
  if ((b%m)==0, return(0));             /* "0" if b divisible by m, or m=1  */
  if ((i==2), return(power2n(b,m,b)));  /* if i==2, calculate  (b^b) mod m  */
  /* boundary cases for m=3n*(3^^3), just detect m>3^^3, similary for 2^^4  */
  /* and similarily for m=2n*(2^^3), just detect m>2^^3                     */
  if ((b==2) && (i==3) && (m>16),            return (16));
  if ((b==2) && (i==4) && (m>65536),         return (65536));
  if ((b==3) && (i==3) && (m>7625597484987), return (7625597484987));
  /* theoretically, there is also (b==4) && (i==3) && (m>4^^3)              */

  log2p=0;
  n=eulerphi(m); /* n replaces m in recursion, reducetower(b,n,i-1); */
  if (n+1<m, /* if m is not a prime */
    log2p=floor(log(m)/log(2)); /* repeating pattern length n guarenteed    */
  );
  rz = reducetower(b,n,i-1);  /* recursion with i-1, and n replacing m      */
  /*  we know there are repeats beginning at or before log2p, so that       */
  /*  b^log2p = b^(log2p+n)                                                 */
  /*  b^b^z can be replaed with b^(b^z mod n) as long as (b^z mod n)>log2p  */
  /*  if b^z<log2p, keep adding (b^z)+n until >= log2p                      */
  while ((log2p>0) && (rz<log2p), rz=rz+n);
  rz = power2n(b,m,rz);  /*  (b^rz) mod m  */
  if (debugprint,
    print("("b"^^"i")%"m"=("b"^(("b"^^"i-1")%"n"))%"m"="rz);
  );
  return(rz);
}
power2n(z,m,i) = {
  local(t,y);
  if (i==0,return(1));
  y=z;
  t=1;
  /* express i in base 2, multiply the subparts of i as they are calculated */
  while ((y<>1) && (i>0),
    if ((i%2)==1, t=(t*y)%m;i=i-1);
    y=(y*y)%m;
    i=i/2;
  );
  return(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your program! I will check some cases.

Comment: Still working on the "proof" of correctness.  It may be awhile...

Comment: Oh, what a pity! So, what about your result of the prime factors of 2^5+3^^5 and 2^^6+3^^6 ?

Comment: sure, which tag is it under?

Comment: I undeleted it. Tags : number-theory, tetration, prime-factors

Comment: I updated the code to fix the boundary condition for (2^^4 mod (2^^4)*2n) which is (2^^4 mod 65536*n), for n=4,6,8,10... For these cases, the algorithm returns zero instead of 2^^4. Similarly, the algorithm also messes up for (3^^3 mod (3^^3)*3n) for example (3^^3 mod 22876792454961). So the simplest solution is that there needs to be a more general dropout, if m>b^^i, then just return(b^^i). I'll eventually modify the pari-gp code.

Comment: @Peter I need to catch up on my modular arithmetic background, which unfortunately isn't very strong, and proving correctness for the boundary conditions I came up with is complicated.

Comment: I installed the software but it warns that it cannot deal directly with more than 80 digits. Anyway, great thanks for this marvellous tool.

Comment: and your function reducetower makes my today question useless, even if it is interesting for itself : [powers of powers of 10 reduction PowerTower](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931658/powers-of-powers-of-10-reduction-powertower) . Thank you so much :)