# Lower and upper bounds for the length of phi-chains wanted

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

For calculating

$$a \uparrow \uparrow n\ (mod\ m)$$

the chain

$$m , \phi(m) , \phi(\phi(m)) , \phi(\phi(\phi(m))) , ... $$

is useful.

As $\phi^n(m)=1$ for some n, the above modulo calculation gets stationary at some point.

So, it would be useful, if the length of the phi-chains could be suitable bounded.

Which lower and upper bounds are there for the least number n with $\phi^n(m)=1$ ?

I calculated the numbers up to about m = 36 * $10^6$ , and the longest chain consisted of 27 numbers until 1 was reached. The start number was the prime 
35946497.

Comment: This question is closely related to another, where I asked how $a \uparrow \uparrow n\ (mod\ m)$ can be calculated. The question how the exponent can be reduced to go on, was discussed and some hints were given, but I still do not know a concrete algorithm that manages all cases. Perhaps someone can figure out it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a more recent reference than

P. Erdős, A. Granville, C. Pomerance and C. Spiro (1990). On the normal behavior of the iterates of some arithmetic functions. In *Analytic number theory* (pp. 165–204). Birkhäuser Boston.

http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/iterate.pdf

The introduction cites a 1929 result of Pillai that

$$\left\lceil\frac{\log m}{\log 3}\right\rceil \le n \le \left\lceil\frac{\log m}{\log 2}\right\rceil,$$

so $n$ actually doesn't vary too wildly from $\log m$.  The extreme values are occupied by powers of $3$ on the low end and powers of $2$ on the high end, so the paper is largely concerned with the normal order of $n$ (conjecturally, $n$ is asymptotic to a constant times $\log m$ for the vast majority of $m$).

Comment: Are these bounds proven or only conjectured ?

Comment: @Peter The bounds are proven (I haven't checked the paper of Pillai myself but it sounds pretty reasonable), the normal order is not.