# Stationary prime factor 34276387 , confirmation and generalization wanted.

Tags: number-theory, tetration, prime-factorization

Sheldon L found out, that

$$34276387$$

is a prime factor of

$$2 \uparrow \uparrow n + 3 \uparrow \uparrow n$$

for any natural number $n \ge 5$.

$2 \uparrow \uparrow n$ leaves the remainder 20853622

$3 \uparrow \uparrow n$ leaves the remainder 13422765

- Can this result be confirmed by induction ?
- Can this result be generalized for arbitary numbers a,b ?

To make the second qeustion clearer :

Is there a natural number n for any natural numbers a,b, such that every
prime factor of $a \uparrow \uparrow n+b \uparrow\uparrow n$ is a prime
factor of $a \uparrow \uparrow s + b\uparrow\uparrow s$ for every $s \ge n$ ?
(If so, n could be called the "stationary point")

Comment: It seems by including "every prime factor", you've included some really huge prime numbers that are on the order of the same size as a^^n+b^^n.  Such a large prime factor, is unlikely to be stationary.  If m is such a large prime factor (a^^n+b^^)%m=0, than the eulerphi(m) chain should also be much larger than n itself.  So my counter conjecture is that the largest prime factors never get frozen, even though the small prime factors do.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: $\forall h >= 6, \> (3\uparrow\uparrow h+2\uparrow\uparrow h) \bmod 4423 = 0$, so there is another small prime factor for h>=6, but it does not work for h=4, or h=5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a narrow answer to the "confirmation" question, showing the required steps to get a rigorous result for arbitrarily large values of n.  The goal is to prove $\forall\> n>0, \> 3 \uparrow\uparrow (n+4) \bmod 34276387 = 13422765$. The key to proving the result directly for $3\uparrow\uparrow 5$ is brute force finding the optimal cycle lengths.

$\forall\> n>0, \> 3 \equiv 3^{n} \pmod 6
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> (3\uparrow\uparrow n) \bmod 6 = 3$

$\forall\> n>0, \> 3^n \equiv 3^{n+6} \pmod {156}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 3\uparrow\uparrow (n+1) \equiv 3^{(3\uparrow\uparrow n)\bmod 6} \equiv 3^3 \equiv 27 \pmod {156}$

$\forall\> n>0, \> 3^n \equiv 3^{n+156} \pmod {94640}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 3\uparrow\uparrow (n+2) \equiv 3^{(3\uparrow\uparrow (n+1))\bmod 156} \equiv 3^{27} \equiv 21867 \pmod {94640}$

$\forall\> n>0, \> 3^n \equiv 3^{n+94640} \pmod {34276386}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 3\uparrow\uparrow (n+3) \equiv 3^{(3\uparrow\uparrow (n+2))\bmod 94640} \equiv 3^{21867} \equiv 7088973 \pmod {34276386}$

$3^n \equiv 3^{n+34276386} \pmod {34276387}
\\ \therefore \>\forall\> n>0, \> 3\uparrow\uparrow (n+4) \equiv 3^{(3\uparrow\uparrow (n+3))\bmod 34276386} \equiv 3^{7088973} \equiv 13422765 \pmod {34276387}$

The goal is also to prove $2\uparrow\uparrow (n+4) \bmod 34276387 = 20853622 \>\forall\> n>0$.
The key to proving the result directly for $2\uparrow\uparrow5$ is getting the optimal cycle lengths.  At each step, of course if m>z
$(z \bmod m)=z$, and in fact for $2\uparrow\uparrow 5$, the recursive steps return exactly $2\uparrow\uparrow n$.  This is why the recursion result differs for $2\uparrow\uparrow 4$

$\forall\> n>0, \> 2\uparrow\uparrow (n+1) = 2^{2\uparrow\uparrow n}  \>\text{and}\>  2^n \bmod 2 = 0
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> (2\uparrow\uparrow n) \bmod 2 = 0 \>\text{and}\> (2\uparrow\uparrow n) >=2
$

$\forall\> n>1, \> 2^n \equiv 2^{n+2} \pmod {12}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 2\uparrow\uparrow (n+1) \equiv 2^{2+(2\uparrow\uparrow n)\bmod 2} \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {12}$

$\forall\> n>2, \> 2^n \equiv 2^{n+12} \pmod {3640}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 2\uparrow\uparrow (n+2) \equiv 2^{(2\uparrow\uparrow (n+1))\bmod 12} \equiv 2^4 \equiv 16 \pmod {3640}$

$\forall\> n>0, \> 2^n \equiv 2^{n+3640} \pmod {34276386}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 2\uparrow\uparrow (n+3) \equiv 2^{(3\uparrow\uparrow (n+2))\bmod 3640} \equiv 2^{16} \equiv 65536 \pmod {34276386}$

$2^n \equiv 2^{n+34276386} \pmod {34276387}
\\ \therefore \forall\> n>0, \> 2\uparrow\uparrow (n+4) \equiv 2^{(2\uparrow\uparrow (n+3))\bmod 34276386} \equiv 2^{65536} \equiv 20853622 \pmod {34276387}$

Finally, $13422765+20853622=34276387 \therefore \> \forall\>n>4,$ 
$$(3\uparrow\uparrow n) + (2\uparrow\uparrow n) \equiv 0 \pmod {34276387}$$

By contrast, the pari-gp program, from [my answer to a previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630134/calculating-an-pmod-m-in-the-general-case), using the unoptimized chain length, always iterating $m\mapsto\phi(m)$ gets the same result, and can give results to arbitrary tetration heights, but the "proof" would involve checking all tetration heights<=24.