# Checking primality for $2 \uparrow \uparrow n + 3 \uparrow \uparrow n$

Tags: prime-numbers, tetration, primality-test

Is there a clever way to test primality for

$$2 \uparrow \uparrow n \quad + \quad 3 \uparrow \uparrow n$$

where $n \gt 3$? (Not surprisingly, I got stuck after that)

For $n \le 3$ we get:

$$
\begin{matrix}
2 \uparrow \uparrow 0 \quad + \quad 3 \uparrow \uparrow 0 & = &  1 + 1  & = &   2 & (\text{prime}) & (\text{...}) \\
2 \uparrow \uparrow 1 \quad + \quad 3 \uparrow \uparrow 1 & = &  2 + 3  & = &   5 & (\text{prime}) & (\text{yes}) \\
2 \uparrow \uparrow 2 \quad + \quad 3 \uparrow \uparrow 2 & = &  2^2 + 3^3  & = &   31 & (\text{prime}) & (\text{okay}) \\
2 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \quad + \quad 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 & = &  2^{2^2} + 3^{3^3}  & = & 7625597485003 & (\text{prime}) & (\text{hmm...}) \\
\end{matrix}
$$

**Example:**

One simple way to rule out primality is to check if the last digit of the sum is $5$. Now we know that the last digit of $2^k$ and $3^k$ follow a pattern such that for $2^k$ with $k \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ the last digit is $6$ and for $3^k$ with $k \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ the last digit is $7$. From this we can state that for $n \gt 2$ the last digit of  $2 \uparrow \uparrow n$ will be $6$ and for $n \gt 1$ the last digit of $3 \uparrow \uparrow n$ will be $7$, which means we can't rule out primality this way.

Comment: Very similar question : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634844/stationary-prime-factor-34276387-confirmation-and-generalization-wanted?lq=1

Comment: Sheldon found a prime factor of $2\uparrow\uparrow 5+3\uparrow \uparrow 5$

Comment: I am currently searching a prime factor of $2\uparrow\uparrow 4+3\uparrow\uparrow 4$. There is no small factor, but the number is so large that it is composite with a very high probability.

Comment: If $2\uparrow\uparrow 4+3\uparrow\uparrow 4$ happens to be prime, it will be virtually hopeless to prove this, or even detect that it is a probable prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n$ large enough ($n \ge 6$) ,$ 2\uparrow \uparrow n \equiv 2197 \pmod {4423}$ and $3 \uparrow \uparrow n \equiv 2226 \pmod {4423}$, and so $2 \uparrow \uparrow n + 3\uparrow \uparrow n$ is always a multiple of $4423$.

Assuming the limit of $a \uparrow \uparrow n$ modulo $p$ is "random" in $\Bbb F_p^*$, you can expect to get $2\uparrow \uparrow n +3\uparrow \uparrow n \to 0 \pmod p$ with probability about $1/p$.

The sum over all primes of $1/p$ diverges, so we can expect that there are infinitely many such primes. $4423$ is the smallest such prime.

So you are left with the cases $n=4$ and $n=5$ to inverstigate.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that $a\uparrow\uparrow n$ converges mod $p$ for generic $a,n$ and primes $p$?

Comment: This is a well-known property of power towers. The base can be reduced modulo $p$, the first exponent modulo $\phi(p)$, the second exponent modulo $\phi(\phi(p))$ and so on. At some point, the exponents all get $1$, so the values must converge. Moreover, this convergence is very quick indeed in most cases. This allows to calculate the last digits of Graham's number, for instance.

Comment: forall $a\ge 0$ and $m \ge 1$, the sequence $(a \uparrow \uparrow n \pmod m)$ is convergent. I recursively computed those limit for every $m < 10^5$ and only found one prime where the sum converged to $0$. (this doesn't rule out $a_n \equiv 0 \pmod p$ for $n=4$ for a small prime $p$)

Answer (score 2):

$$34,276,387$$ is a prime factor of $2\uparrow\uparrow 5+3\uparrow\uparrow 5$ ,found by Sheldon L
(See the link above).

I do not know a prime factor of $2\uparrow\uparrow 4+3\uparrow\uparrow 4$, but the number is very probably composite, and if it is prime, even a probable-prime
test will be out of reach.